# Unable to Register Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

After installing Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8 a dialog box with the following text appears:

"This product will expire in 30 day(s). Registration is required for continued use of Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8" 
[(Image of Dialog Box)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUel6.png)

After clicking the "Register online" link that appears my browser displays an error as follows:

"An unknown error occurred while processing your request. This is most likely due to a connection failure. Please try again. R30EZW-3ab35ca3-9c79-4683-9b15-798284a137bd"
[(Image of error message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Qs9.png)

Anyone have any idea how I can activate this product?

Comment: You should ask this on the Microsoft support forums.

Comment: I did but no luck yet.